# Finding eigenvalues of matrices with specific from

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How do we find the eigenvalues of the matrix
\begin{pmatrix} 
-1 & -1 & -1&-1&-1&\cdots \\ -1 &-2 & -2&-2&-2&\cdots\\ -1 &-2 & -3&-3&-3&\cdots\\
 -1 &-2 & -3&-4&-4&\cdots\\ -1 &-2 & -3&-4&-5&\cdots\\\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&-n
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: minus the matrix has an evident Cholesky form, $M^T M$  with all entries of $M$ either $0$ or $1.$  So my negative is positive definite, and the eigenvalues can be bounded in various ways. However, no closed form of the eigenvalues.